# How to view HTML file from application data on Chrome Browser in android

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm doing Android application which I want to open an HTML file from my application data on Chrome browser without manual interrupt. Currently it's working fine for default browser.But I want to open it on chrome browser.

My Code for default browser:

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
browserIntent.setData(Uri.fromFile(file));
browserIntent.setType("text/html");
browserIntent.setClassName("com.android.browser", "com.android.browser.BrowserActivity");                                                      
browserIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);
browserIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
browserIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
browserIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);
startActivity(browserIntent);
```

How could I proceed that on Chrome browser explicitly.If I tried like `setClassName("com.android.chrome", "com.android.chrome.Main")`, I'm getting exception as

> android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW..." .

Please help me to get out this issue. Is there any other way?Thanks.

Comment: And What if Chrome is not installed in device ? Remember even Google asks you where to open youtube links (broswer/s and Youtube app) which means you have control on what to display (link etc.) but where user want to see it is user's choice. Even if we can do it, we shouldn't.

Comment: amit, My application initially check whether chrome has installed in device or not. Then only it explicitly open html file on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `classname` as

> com.android.chrome/com.google.android.apps.chrome.Main

```
browserIntent.setClassName("com.android.browser", "com.android.chrome/com.google.android.apps.chrome.Main");
```